# Two pages with almost identical scroll events has different performance

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I Have two pages first our blog home page and second our news website home page,
The blog has an annoying lag in chrome when you scroll down our up.
But almost the same code works great in our news website.
You can find both pages below:

[news website](https://news.akhbarrasmi.com/)
[blog](https://blog.akhbarrasmi.com/)

The Problem is: i used chrome developer tools rendering panel to see FPS, Repaint areas, animation tweaks, but i could not find the problem causing lag on blog page.
any ideas on how to find the problem?

Comment: Try to remove the slick-slider on top in the devtools. Seems to increase performance a lot! Maybe you can optimize from there.

Comment: if you add this as an answer i can accept it

Comment: Thanks! Also maybe there's just too many slides. You could try to reduce them. Also, is there something happening in JS on Scroll? Like scroll-position-detection? If so you could take a look at https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the slick-slider on top in the devtools. Seems to increase performance a lot! Maybe you can optimize from there.